# Query about fid in QField causing difficulty digitising

Tags: qgis

I have been using QField for a while and  recently got a  message under `fid` saying NOT NULL, Unique and I can no longer digitise anything on QField. I read that you can make a change under layer properties but the fid field is not showing in any of my layers in QField to make that change.

I am not that experienced so simple directions on how to fix it would be great.

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1480

Comment: Thanks will do. Still not clear but hopefully someone might know

Comment: i'have expérienced the same problem. Fix with QField 1.7.8 (see below)

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue in QField 1.7.7 and is fixed in QField 1.7.8 (soon to be released to the playstore at time of writing).

References:

- https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1480
- https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.7.8

Answer (score 0):

Mary, QField only display configurations made in QGIS. So in QGIS, you need to look at the **Attribute Form** for your layer(s) and check the ***Constraints*** configurations.[image: Attributes Form]